# Magento 2.3 Accidentally delete vendor/magento folder in root directory content [WHM/cPanel] using rm-rf

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, backup, user, vendor

I accidentally deleted vendor/magento folder from WHM/Cpanel using rm -rf command and i don't have any backup is there any possibility to restored that file.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the `composer install` command again. This way the folder inside the vendor will be recreated

Comment: yes it will be recreated, but I did some modification on there so, i need to restore the old one

Comment: Please check my posted answer, it might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can try to recover your modified files using a file recovery tools. These tools can scan your hard drive and recover deleted files, including the vendor/magento folder and its contents.

1. TestDisk - a powerful open-source data recovery software that can recover lost partitions, repair partition tables, and recover deleted files.
2. PhotoRec - another open-source software from the same developers as TestDisk that can recover lost files from various file systems including FAT, NTFS, and HFS+.
3. Disk Drill: This is a comprehensive data recovery tool that can recover deleted or lost files from any storage device. It uses advanced scanning algorithms to recover files from damaged, formatted or corrupted drives.
4. Recuva - a popular data recovery software for Windows that can recover deleted files from hard drives, memory cards, and USB drives.
5. EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard - a comprehensive data recovery software that can recover lost files from different types of storage devices including hard drives, memory cards, and USB drives.

Please note that data recovery is not always possible and the success of data recovery using any tool highly depends on various factors such as the time elapsed since the deletion, the amount of data written on the drive after the deletion, and the file system used. It is always best to regularly backup important data to avoid such situations.

Comment: Is it possible to recover data from cPanel/WHM?

Comment: As for the possibility of recovering data from cPanel/WHM, it depends on various factors such as the file system, the storage media, and the extent of the damage caused by the deletion. In general, if the data has not been overwritten, there is a possibility of recovering it using data recovery tools. However, it is important to note that data recovery is not guaranteed and the success rate depends on various factors.

Comment: I never use TestDisk or other methods can you please tell me the steps for using this on the WHM/Cpanel terminal?